# Logback sfl4j MDC unique for http request

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback, mdc

I'm working with Sping Boot 1.5.7. The application offers API Restful.
I have a Filter where I set the MDC with username and transaction id.

```
    MDC.put("user", authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
    MDC.put("trans-id",authentication.getTokenId());
```

I want to have a MDC map for each request, instead the MDC data are shared among different request.

Can you help me please? Thanks.

UPDATE:

In log below every row is a http request:

```
2017-11-10 21:34:52.867 | user=USER, trans-id=c28f4b68-b5f3-4b5c-9bb5-f18ba9d1cd7d, session-id=daaddaadda |   INFO 976 - [tp1005246661-89] i.e.h.controller.IsAliveController       : /isAlive WSC | 

2017-11-10 21:34:59.551 | user=USER, trans-id=4a0eaec1-184a-4587-8fce-ab013ad6539b, session-id=daaddaadda |   INFO 976 - [tp1005246661-89] i.e.h.controller.IsAliveController       : /isAlive public |
```

In second request I set only trans-id, instead in MDC map there are session-id and user setted in first request.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using logback as logging implementation, and at any point of time, one thread is handling one request till completion. As per [documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html), MDC is already stored per thread, hence it will be sufficient for your use case. In our project, we use MDC to keep track of thread id (not thread name) for debugging purpose, it's working as expected

> The MDC manages contextual information on a per thread basis. Typically, while starting to service a new client request, the developer will insert pertinent contextual information, such as the client id, client's IP address, request parameters etc. into the MDC

Comment: I have updated my post with more information. Thanks.

Comment: Understand. You can clear MDC values in spring interceptor. Overriding `HandlerInterceptorAdapter#preHandle` might be just sufficient

Comment: Do you have some example please?

Comment: Sure, i just quickly test this. It seems working fine

Comment: Ok. I Will try It. Now I have cleared MDC map before first initialize. It seems working fine. Thanks

Comment: code seems too long for comment, so post as answer only.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {
            LOG.info("Inside pre-handle");
            MDC.clear();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, Exception e) throws Exception 
{

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. the interceptor starts before of filter?

Comment: exactly, for each incoming request, MDC will be clear first and will come to actual request handler

Comment: I Will try It. Thanks

Comment: @Apolozeus perhpas you should edit your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47229425/8200937) (by clicking on the `edit` link beneath the answer) rather than posting a second answer to the same question?

Comment: @Apolozeus in my case I have insert MDC.clear() in FIlter. The Filter is executed before of Interceptor. Thanks.

Comment: @Michel Foucault Oh good to know, thanks for your info. It might be helpful for me in future.